# Jenkins use docker to build maven image cannot access to nexus

Tags: maven, security, docker, jenkins, nexus

I am using a Jenkins pipeline to download my code and building it inside the official maven container

```
 pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
           stage('Back-end build') {
            agent {
                docker { 
                    image 'maven'
                    label 'master'       
                 }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -f de.vitasystems.qrcode.generator/pom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings.xml  clean package'
                stash includes: 'target/*.war', name: 'app' 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After doing that I realized that I need the settings.xml for the nexus repository configuration and the settings-security.xml in order to allow to download it.
Then I did this:

1. I had created another Dockerfile that use the maven one (FROM maven)
   and it copy the necessary files setting.xml and for been used in the
   previous pipeline.
2. It is referring to the correct repository but it is not authorized to download files

Add the security-settings.xml is needed in order to be able to download the data from my nexus (maven nexus password) but I can not reference it or use it.

How can I use the security-settings.xml in this container?? Maven documentation says that I put the file in the $HOME/.m2 folder but it is not working.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found the solution, the setting-security are not used until you are with the root user.
I make a Dockerfile to create a new docker images that wrap-up:

```
FROM maven
COPY settings.xml /root/.m2/settings.xml
COPY settings-security.xml root/.m2/settings-security.xml

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["mvn"]
```

This image will wrap-up the security configuration but for be able to be use in the jenkinsfile you need to run the container using root user. 
Example

```
agent {
     docker { 
        image 'maven'
        label 'master'
        args '-u root'
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use the config file provider plugin , he will copy the settings.xml from the master into your workspace

```
stage('Build')
            {
                steps {
                configFileProvider(
                        [configFile(fileId: 'your-id-xxx', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
                    sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS clean install -P integration-tests'
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for the info but I found the solution and I will explain now.